# estoy creando una tienda en linea,pero cuando intento guardar los productos al carrito de compras este no los guarda,estoy usando variables de sesion

Tags: php

mi problema es el siguiente estoy creando una tienda en linea,pero cuando intento guardar los productos al carrito de compras este no los guarda,estoy usando variables de sesion, si alguien puede ayudarme se los agradecería mucho, llevo probando muchos códigos y no me funciona :(

```
// ESTE ES MI Conexion//
<?php

class conexionDB{

    public function getConexion(){
        $cnx = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tiendavirtual","root","");
        return $cnx;

    }
}
```

trabaja bien ala hora de mostrar todos los productos de la base de datos, pero justo cuando quiero guardar los productos al carrito no los guarda solo muestra la estructura del formulario y los campos vacios , me ayudaria muchisimo si me pueden orientar para poder resolver el problema , no puedo avanzar si no lo resulelvo:(

````
#este es el codigo de mi cesta#

<!DOCTYPE html>


<?php 

session_start();

include '../DAO/metodosDAO.php';

?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="../bootstrap-5.1.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="text-center">cesta de productos</h2>

    <table border="1" align="center" width="400">

    <?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['cesta'])){
      
        $total=0;

 

foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $id => $x){

    $objMetodos=new metodosDAO();
    $lista=$objMetodos->listarProductosCod($id);
               
               $nombre =$lista[1];
               $precio =$lista[2];
               $costo=$x * $precio;
               $total=$total + $costo;
             
                
               ?>

               <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $nombre;?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $precio;?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $x; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $costo;?></td>
               </tr>


<?php
       }
    
    ?>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
    <td ><?php echo $total;?></td>
</tr>

<?php
       }

    
    ?>
    </table>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="../bootstrap-5.1.0-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
        ``` 
//esto son mis Funciones //
<?php

include '../Utils/conexionDB.php';

class metodosDAO{
 
    public function listarProductos(){
     
        $cnx= new conexionDB();
        $cn= $cnx->getConexion();

        $res= $cn->prepare("select * from productos");
        $res->execute();

        foreach ($res as $row){
            $lista[]=$row;
        }

        return $lista;
    }


    public function listarProductosCod($cod){
     
        $cnx= new conexionDB();
        $cn= $cnx->getConexion();

        $res= $cn->prepare("select * from productos where codpro=$cod");
        $res->execute();

        foreach ($res as $row){
            $lista[]=$row;
        }

        return $lista;
    }






}
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Hola Eli, te sugiero reestructurar tu codigo, por meramente detalles de estetica y orden, ya que de esta forma es muy dificil pedir ayuda y no tener un codigo estructurado porque solamente tu lo entiendes, en tanto a los productos lo que estas haciendo es seleccionar los productos de la base de datos y no de donde el usuario los va eligiendo, que es la idea de una cesta, mediante `$_SESSION[]` almacena la id de los items que va seleccionando y luego muestralas en un arreglo